# How can i resolve .net MAUI dependencies errors?

Tags: c#, .net, dependencies, maui

i'm with a big problem, hope someone can help me.
Well, I made the Visual Studio 2022 Preview download, having focus on .NET MAUI. But after creating a new Project, i have dependencies errors, especifically Nuget packages...

[Click to See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puHwD.png)

I did try to update the packages, but the buttons are desabled* and i got that message as shown in the image bellow: "**implicit reference by sdk. to update the package, update the sdk it belongs to**"

[Click to See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h09hT.png)

I checked if there are updates in .NET SDK, but it says that its all up to date!!!

I have no ideas what should i do to fix it

1 - Update .NET SDK
2 - Reinstall VS 2022 Preview
3 - ReDownload all Nuget Packages

Comment: Uninstall the preview SDK and install the latest SDK from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/visual-studio-sdks. I had the same problem.

Comment: whats the especific .net preview sdk version?

Comment: According to the official documentation: If you have a preview installed of the requested .NET SDK version, you also need to set the option to enable previews in Visual Studio. Go to Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features, and make sure that Use previews of the .NET Core SDK is checked. For more information you can check it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1045).

Comment: in my case, the missing dependencies were NuGet Packages that downloaded automatically after a relatively large amount of time without any message to me that i should wait for it!!